# How to extrapolate smoothly, based on discrete values

Tags: finance, lagrange-interpolation, extrapolation

I am trying to figure out how to value a property (piece of land) based on the original purchase price, and shifted proportional to irregular government valuations.

This is for the purpose of a legal contract, to decide what price a property will be purchased in the future.

Our government values a piece of land at irregular periods. So for example (not the actual figures),

in year 2000 it might have been $100k

in 2006 $140k

in 2008 $130k

in 2014 $150k

Lets say the property was purchased for a figure of $170k in 2012

The "value" is expected to be proportional to purchase price and changed in line with the government valuations.

How would I go about calculating this new "value"?

I was looking at Lagrange (using online calculators) for getting a curve of government valuations. Would you consider this a fair way?

ps. Its been decades since I did any serious maths... ;)

Comment: For this you need a *model* of how value vary with time, which could be any number of things. This has been researched for decades and there are no "best" models, AFAIK, so your problem is a bit undefined, unfortunately. You need to set up more specific criteria for how the new value is predicted.

Comment: Ok thanks, what further criteria do I need? Also, I'm looking for a fair way that would be agreed between parties, not necessarily a perfect way.

Comment: These are waay too broad questions to address here. As there is no best model, I cannot say which criteria/assumptions you would need to make, it all depends on how you want the model to behave. I'd suggest you ask another question asking for resources (articles and the like) listing different, current models that might be appropriate for your scenario. Good luck!